# Does C++ have any runtime metaprogramming functionality?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

By "runtime metaprogramming" I mean changing the actual code at runtime.

For example, take this code:

```
while (true) {
   if (flag) {
      //do stuff
   }
   //do other stuff
}
```

Let's say something happens so that flag will always be false/true, so there is no need to keep checking its value. It would be nice to just "get rid" of the if statement. Obviously there might just be better design in the code before execution to handle this, but this is just an example.

Comment: There is usually no need to optimize code on that level. For this specific issue, modern processors use branch prediction so that in most cases a check for a constant flag will be skipped by the processor directly. See [Wikipedia on Branch Prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor)

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: "*Let's say something happens so that flag will always be false/true*" If that could happen, then who's to say that something else couldn't happen to change the state of `flag`? "*It would be nice to just "get rid" of the if statement.*" Um, why?

Comment: Nope, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @NineBerry if the branch will be correctly predicted, the check still cannot be skipped, it needs to be done to be able to verify that the prediction was correct. It's off of the critical path, but still has throughput implications (depending on the code, the impact can be zero, since throughput costs are not strictly additive)

Comment: @NicolBolas what if you were writing a GUI application, and a there was code checking for clicking on a window. Let’s say then the window was closed and would never be able to be reopened. We wouldn’t care about checking to see if we were clicking on that window anymore.

Comment: If I were writing a GUI application, clicking on a button would emit a signal that would cause a handler to become activated. I wouldn't have some `while(true) { // Do stuff ... if(buttonClicked()) { // Do other stuff } }` thing

Comment: @beangod: Even if there was code specifically checking to see if the window was clicked (which as Nathan pointed out, isn't how GUIs work), that code would be bound *to the window*. It would be a thing the window does when it is active and therefore not something that happens when it is inactive. Furthermore, things change; today, you might think that the window could "never" be reopened, but them some design changes and now it needs to be able to be reopened.

Comment: The language doesn't support this directly, but it is possible to write code that does the sort of thing that you want; e.g. create an abstract `class ITask` with a `virtual void doSomething() = 0;` method, and create various subclasses that do various things, and finally create vector/list of these objects that the `while(true)`-loop iterates over, calling `doSomething()` on each in turn -- when you no longer want to do a task, you remove it from the vector/list and now the checks no longer occur for that task.

Comment: Keep in mind that in the modern OoO CPUs "branch is taken" is free. You pay the penalty for branch not taken, usually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ does not have facilities for modifying code at runtime like that.  This is because C++ code is compiled to machine code, and modifying machine code is very difficult, insecure, and non-portable.  If you're interested, see the Wikipedia article on [Self-modifying code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code).

In theory, if you really needed to, you could hoist the test for `flag` further back, by writing three sets of functions (one where `flag` is known to be always true, one where it's always false, and one where it could be either) and switch between those sets of functions at an earlier time.  However, the code complexity and performance impact of maintaining three separate copies of the functions will not be worth the microscopic speedup from removing one easily-predicted branch.

If you're concerned about the performance of your application, you will find better opportunities for optimization elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> Does C++ have any runtime metaprogramming functionality?

The abstract machine that a compiler has to have in mind when optimizing and organizing instructions does not involve the volatile nature of someone flipping a bit somewhere in memory that it can't control. That "somewhere" may not even exist after the compiler has done its job.

In the case of the `true` check in your loop:
None of the compilers I know will actually produce code that checks if there is a `true` there. It's just a an infinite loop.

Why? The compiler has to produce a program acting "as-if" it did all you instructed it to do. If you instruct it to check if `true` is `true`, the "as-if" rule tells the compiler that it can with a 100% certainty rely on the fact that you want this loop to go on forever. No runtime check necessary.